# Is 170 mb of database is too large just for 350 posts?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and there are only about 350 posts. After cleaning all post revisions, spam comments and optimizing database, its 170 mb. When I check phpmyadmin, comment meta is 152 mb and i have 700 comments. Is it too large? How can I reduce the size?

Comment: check if your comment has spam in it. If so, delete those data.

Comment: No it is not to large. Or do you running into some issues? Check for spam comments that are still saved in the db, but they should deletable from admin backend.

Comment: post the size of the three top tables

Answer (score 1):

optimizing is not cleaning, optimizing is simply rearranging the data for faster access. you need to remove redundant data from the mysql database. here are 7 mysql query to clean up your bloated database.

http://www.geckoandfly.com/12815/10-must-use-sql-queries-clean-wordpress-bloated-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the SPAM comments are not deleted permanently. Delete the spam comments permanently and the comment meta table size will come down to few kbs.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

In the past I had the same problem, this article helped me: http://thecustomizewindows.com/2011/12/reduce-wp_commentmeta-table-database-size-in-wordpress/

Good luck! :)